# Need SPModerationStatusType any dependencie in SPO for use in Client Side?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

Untill last week, i was using SPModerationStatusType to do the Approbe of Draft items in a list in client side, but this week, the same application without changes doesn't work.

I need any dependencie to use it in client side with JavaScript?

thnks.

Answer (score 0):

Approve Item use JavaScript like below:

```
function approveItem(listId,itemId,comment,success,error) {
   var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getById(listId);
   var item = list.getItemById(itemId);

   item.set_item('_ModerationStatus',0);
   item.set_item('_ModerationComments',comment);
   item.update();

   context.executeQueryAsync(
       function(){
           success();
       }, 
       error
    );   
}
```

Comment: Of course, i do it in that way, but i can't use the enum SPModerationStatusType, that a week ago it works perfect, 
instead of the string '0'.